# how to iterate 2 set data in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is it possible to iterate 2 set data in ng repeat, or i have to merge 2 set data into 1?

```
<tbody>
 <tr ng-repeat="data1 in student_data, data2 in teacher_data | limitTo: itemsPerPage : currentTop">
    <td>{{data1.student_name}}</td>
    <td>{{data2.teacher_name}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: you can have one ng-repeat inside of the other

Comment: So this will work? <td ng-repeat="data1 in student_data">{{data1.student_data}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="data2 in teacher_data">{{data2.teacher_data}}</td>

Comment: the code in your comment will print all the students... followed by all the teachers... is that what you're looking for ?

Comment: No, i want to print a column of student and a column of teacher!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want...

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.students = ['student1' ,'student2' ,'student3' ,'student4' ,'student5' ,'student6'];
    $scope.teachers = ['teacher1' ,'teacher2' ,'teacher3' ,'teacher4' ,'teacher5'];
    
});
```

```css
table, th , td  {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in students" ng-init="outerIndex=$index">
     <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
     <td>{{ x }}</td>
     <ng-container >
        <td ng-repeat="y in teachers" ng-init="innerIndex=$index" ng-show="$index==$parent.$index">
         <ng-container >
          <span>{{y}}</span> 
         </ng-container>
          </td>
     </ng-container>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```